# How to create an automation runbooks with Python type?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ansible, azure-cli, azure-runbook

I create an automation runbooks by azure cli
az automation runbook create --automation-account-name "Testing" --name "test_run_book" --resource-group "my_rg" --type "Python"
But when i run , it show type error .
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Python is not an accepted value for 'type'; these are the accepted values from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/automation/runbook?view=azure-cli-latest#az-automation-runbook-create):

Graph, GraphPowerShell, GraphPowerShellWorkflow, PowerShell, PowerShellWorkflow, Script

EDIT: As of 09/03/22, It is not possible to create a Python runbook using Azure CLI but it is possible using [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/new-azautomationrunbook?view=azps-7.3.0)

Comment: so how can i add type Python if not on azure portal ?

Comment: Currently it's not possible to create a Python runbook from the Azure CLI. It is however possible from [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/new-azautomationrunbook?view=azps-7.3.0)